# How to take a screenshot with a maximum resolution in C

Tags: c, winapi

I am using the following code to take a screenshot in C on Windows (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image).

```
int captureImage(HWND hWnd, char * filename){
    HDC hdcScreen;
    HDC hdcWindow;
    HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
    BITMAP bmpScreen;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    DWORD dwSizeofDIB = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    char* lpbitmap = NULL;
    HANDLE hDIB = NULL;
    DWORD dwBmpSize = 0;

    // retrieve handle to display device content 
    hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

    // Create a compatible DC (domain controller)
    hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);
    if (!hdcMemDC){
        printf("Error creating hdcMemDC\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Make process DPI aware to avoid wrongly sized screenshots when screen resolution changes
    SetProcessDPIAware();

    // get area for size calculations
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

    // use this stretch mode
    SetStretchBltMode(hdcWindow, HALFTONE);

    // the source DC is the entire screen, and the destination in the current window (for now)
    StretchBlt(hdcWindow, 0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, hdcScreen, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), SRCCOPY);

    // create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC
    hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top);
    if (!hbmScreen){
        printf("Error creating hmbScreen\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Select the compatible bitmap into the memory DC
    SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    // transfer bits into the memory DC
    BitBlt(hdcMemDC, 0, 0, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top, hdcWindow, 0 , 0, SRCCOPY);

    // get the bitmap from the hbitmap
    GetObject(hbmScreen, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpScreen);

    // bitmap file header and info header
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;

    // set all values for info header
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount+31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;

    hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);
    lpbitmap = (char*)GlobalLock(hDIB);

    // get the bits from the bitmap and copy them into the buffer
    GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0, (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight, lpbitmap, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // create a file to save the capture into
    hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // get the total size of the file
    dwSizeofDIB = dwBmpSize + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // offset to where our bitmap actually starts
    bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // size of the file
    bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB;

    // always set bfType to BM for bitmaps
    bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; // that's BM

    // write data to the file
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    // unlock and free stuff
    GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
    GlobalFree(hDIB);

    // close file handle
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    // Clean everything up

    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);

    return 0; // for normal exit
}
```

Passing in the return value of `GetDesktopWindow()` will take a screenshot of the entire screen and save it a to a file with `filename`. The screenshot is the size of and has the resolution of the screen. So, if used on a 4k screen, that will be the resolution of the screenshot. I was wondering what the best way was to cap this at, say, 1080p. So even if the resolution is greater than 1080x1920, the screenshot will not go higher.

Comment: Scale it down before saving it.

Comment: @tkausl How do I do that? I do not fully understand the code I have written here as I got it from the microsoft docs page that I linked so I am unfamiliar.

Comment: You can try [Scaling an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/scaling-an-image). But [StretchBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt) doesn't convert bitmaps to specific resolution.

Comment: "_I do not fully understand the code_" means you need to ask specific questions, yourself or others. -- "_I am unfamiliar_" means that you need to do some research and to learn. Use your web search skills.

Answer (score 1):

use such code

```
ULONG captureImage(_In_ ULONG cx, _In_ PCWSTR filename)
{
    struct BMEX 
    {
        USHORT ForAlign;
        BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
        UCHAR Bits[];
    };

    ULONG cxScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), cyScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    ULONG cy = cyScreen * cx / cxScreen;

    ULONG size = ((3 * cx + sizeof(ULONG) - 1) & ~(sizeof(ULONG) - 1)) * cy;

    ULONG dwError;

    if (HANDLE hSection = CreateFileMappingW(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size + sizeof(BMEX), 0))
    {
        BITMAPINFO bi = { 
            { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), cx, cy, 1, 24, BI_RGB, size } 
        };

        PVOID Bits;
        
        if (HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBSection(0, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &Bits, hSection, __builtin_offsetof(BMEX, Bits)))
        {
            if (HDC hdc = GetDC(0))
            {
                if (HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(0))
                {
                    HGDIOBJ h = SelectObject(hMemDC, hbmp);

                    if (StretchBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, cx, cy, hdc, 0, 0, cxScreen, cyScreen, SRCCOPY))
                    {
                        HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(filename, FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);

                        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                        {
                            BMEX* p = CONTAINING_RECORD(Bits, BMEX, Bits);
                            p->bfh.bfType = 'MB';
                            p->bfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
                            p->bfh.bfSize = size += sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
                            p->bfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
                            p->bfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
                            memcpy(&p->bih, &bi.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

                            dwError = WriteFile(hFile, &p->bfh, size, &size, 0) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

                            CloseHandle(hFile);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dwError = GetLastError();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dwError = GetLastError();
                    }

                    SelectObject(hMemDC, h);

                    DeleteDC(hMemDC);
                }
                else
                {
                    dwError = GetLastError();
                }

                ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
            }
            else
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
            }

            DeleteObject(hbmp);
        }
        else
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
        }

        CloseHandle(hSection);

        return dwError;
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

Comment: This is performing point-sampling, resulting in very noticeable visual artifacts. A call to [`SetStretchBltMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setstretchbltmode) with a value of `HALFTONE` mitigates the effects. Text rendered using ClearType will still look wonky after scaling.

Comment: @IInspectableyes, this not optimized for best quality effect. but most simply code